# Dynamically Change File Name - ComboBox Excel Print

Tags: excel, vba

How can I have the name of the pdf dynamically changed based on Sel_Manager (combobox1) ?  The viewers would like to print multiple PDFs and show them on the screen at the same time.  Thank you in advance!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sel_Manager As String
'Specify headers to be repeated at the top
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$5:$9"
        .PrintTitleColumns = "$B:$M"
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

'Manager selection through simple Inputbox
 Sel_Manager = ComboBox1
'Insert autofilter for worksheet
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
'Select manager defined in inputbox
ActiveSheet.Range("B14", Range("M14").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sel_Manager
 'Select range to be printed and specify manager in filename
ActiveSheet.Range("B14", Range("M14").End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"Manager.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: `sheet1.sel_manager.value & ".pdf"`

Comment: I am receiving a "Method or Data Member not found" error ?  I checked and it is Sheet1 that I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found -

```
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Sel_Manager + ".pdf",
```